# How to trigger buttons in any windows application

Tags: windows, autohotkey

In most cases, I can use autohotkey to bind hotkeys for a function/feature/button to applications in Windows.

If a software does not have hotkeys for a button and does not provide features to custom-map keys to that button, I used to use image recognition or location of the button. Both are somewhat easy to break.

Does anyone know if there is a better way to target buttons?

for example, "Bold" in Excel has a hotkey, while the Fill Cell Color does not:

-

[image]

-

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [control clicking](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm) a button on Excel. May or may not work nicely and easily.

For an actually good solution, I'd recommend looking into [VBA](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html).
Or if you want to use AHK look into using the [Excel ComObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object)).

Here's a quick little AHK code snippet to turn the currently active cell red:

```
XL := ComObjActive("Excel.Application") ;reference our open Excel document
XL.ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex := 3
```

For VBA you'll find loads of tutorials etc with a quick Google search.
For AHK you'll find some as well, but maybe not as many.
Here's one for AHK that seems to cover a good amount of stuff, however, seems like you'll want to use his library for all that he does. I guess be easy if you just want to get the job done, but not very good if you actually want to learn how to do it:
https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=63032

EDIT:
Just realized Excel was the example, instead of the fill color button. So I'll add some more about control clicking and [control sending](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm).
Use some way to try to get the class, or even more preferably the handle, of the control you wish to click or input to. The controlclick/send AHK documentation pages give some example ways for this.
A possibly easy way could be to use WindowSpy.ahk (an ahk script that with the ahk installation, you'll find it in your install folder). Might also be named something like AU3_Spy.exe.
If you can't get a class or hwnd, you can use coordinates.
The documentation also shows this and has examples.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could take is using the Quick Access Toolbar:

1. Add Fill Cell Color to your Quick Access Toolbar, and
2. Define a hotkey that navigates to the toolbar option. In my case shown further below, this would be a script that sends the keys <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>6</kbd> in sequence.

You can then select a fill color using arrow and enter keys.

This tested okay for me using the below:

```
; Go to Fill Cell Color using Alt+Shift+f
#IfWinActive, ahk_class XLMAIN
!+f::
Send !6
Return
```

The benefit is negligible in this example as you could simply enter <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>6</kbd> manually, but using the Toolbar with AHK is useful in more complex examples.

The downside of this approach is that the script would need to customised for use on a different machine, as the Quick Access Toolbar numbering may vary.

---

[image: Add to Quick Access Toolbar]

[image: Shortcut provided by Excel]

Comment: Thanks! I also use the same idea for Excel, but not all windows applications have quick access toolbar, and it is also limited in number of features you can bind to.

Comment: @Rok Ooohh, I see - sorry, I just realised your question is actually phrased for Windows applications in general. I'll have a think about this one!